# Cannot retrieve a document using GET API

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using Elasticsearch version 1.2.0

I have documents indexed by bulk indexing.

When it comes to search, it works fine when I use _search endpoint to get a document that I want.
However, I cannot get the exactly same document using GET API.

For example, the code snippet below does not retrieve any result.

```
curl -XGET "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9200/my_index/my_type/my_id?pretty"
```

However, when I specify the routing value, it retrieves correct result that I wanted to get.

```
curl -XGET "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9200/my_index/my_type/my_id?routing=3&pretty"
```

Here is the thing that I want to know because **I've never used any kind of routing settings** for indexing operation.

And there is **NO parent-child relations** with the "my_type".

Could anyone recommend other possible reasons for this kind of problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elasticsearch version 1.2.0 has a severe bug with respect to indexing. 
The document recommends an [upgrade to 1.2.1](http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/elasticsearch-1-2-1-released/).I think you are running into this issue.

Comment: Thank you keety. Your answer is exactly right. I have to upgrade the version of Elasticsearch.